# Vectorized spherical bessel functions in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, bessel-functions

I noticed that [`scipy.special`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html) Bessel functions of order n and argument x `jv(n,x)` are vectorized in x:

`In [14]: import scipy.special as sp
In [16]: sp.jv(1, range(3))  # n=1, [x=0,1,2]
Out[16]: array([ 0., 0.44005059, 0.57672481])`

But there's no corresponding vectorized form of the spherical Bessel functions, `sp.sph_jn`:

```
In [19]: sp.sph_jn(1,range(3)) 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ea59d2f45497> in <module>()
----> 1 sp.sph_jn(1,range(3)) #n=1, 3 value array

/home/glue/anaconda/envs/fibersim/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/basic.pyc in sph_jn(n, z)
    262     """
    263     if not (isscalar(n) and isscalar(z)):
--> 264         raise ValueError("arguments must be scalars.")
    265     if (n != floor(n)) or (n < 0):
    266         raise ValueError("n must be a non-negative integer.")

ValueError: arguments must be scalars.
```

Furthermore, the spherical Bessel function compute all orders of N in one pass.  So if I wanted the `n=5` Bessel function for argument `x=10`, it returns n=1,2,3,4,5.  It actually returns jn and its derivative in one pass:

```
In [21]: sp.sph_jn(5,10)
Out[21]: 
(array([-0.05440211,  0.07846694,  0.07794219, -0.03949584, -0.10558929,
        -0.05553451]),
 array([-0.07846694, -0.0700955 ,  0.05508428,  0.09374053,  0.0132988 ,
        -0.07226858]))
```

Why does this asymmetry exist in the API, and does anyone know of a library that will return spherical Bessel functions vectorized, or at least more quickly (ie in cython)?

Comment: It's a known feature request in scipy.special (with some guidance on how to implement the vectorized versions of these): https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3113.

Comment: If anyone has an out-of-the box implementation, please post!  Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a cython function to speedup the calculation, the first thing you must to do is to get the address of the fortran function `SPHJ`, here is how to do this in Python:

```
from scipy import special as sp
sphj = sp.specfun.sphj

import ctypes
addr = ctypes.pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(ctypes.py_object(sphj._cpointer))
```

Then you can call the fortran function directly in Cython, note I use `prange()` to use multicore to speedup the calculation:

```
%%cython -c-Ofast -c-fopenmp --link-args=-fopenmp
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free
from cython.parallel import prange
import numpy as np
import cython
from cpython cimport PyCObject_AsVoidPtr
from scipy import special

ctypedef void (*sphj_ptr) (const int *n, const double *x, 
                            const int *nm, const double *sj, const double *dj) nogil

cdef sphj_ptr _sphj=<sphj_ptr>PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(special.specfun.sphj._cpointer)


@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def cython_sphj2(int n, double[::1] x):
    cdef int count = x.shape[0]
    cdef double * sj = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(count * sizeof(double) * (n + 1))
    cdef double * dj = <double *>PyMem_Malloc(count * sizeof(double) * (n + 1))
    cdef int * mn    = <int *>PyMem_Malloc(count * sizeof(int))
    cdef double[::1] res = np.empty(count)
    cdef int i
    if count < 100:
        for i in range(x.shape[0]):
            _sphj(&n, &x[i], mn + i, sj + i*(n+1), dj + i*(n+1))
            res[i] = sj[i*(n+1) + n]    #choose the element you want here        
    else:
        for i in prange(count,  nogil=True):
            _sphj(&n, &x[i], mn + i, sj + i*(n+1), dj + i*(n+1))
            res[i] = sj[i*(n+1) + n]    #choose the element you want here
    PyMem_Free(sj)
    PyMem_Free(dj)
    PyMem_Free(mn)
    return res.base
```

To compare, here is the Python function that call `sphj()` in a forloop:

```
import numpy as np
def python_sphj(n, x):
    sphj = special.specfun.sphj
    res = np.array([sphj(n, v)[1][n] for v in x])
    return res
```

Here is the %timit results for 10 elements:

```
x = np.linspace(1, 2, 10)
r1 = cython_sphj2(4, x)
r2 = python_sphj(4, x)
assert np.allclose(r1, r2)
%timeit cython_sphj2(4, x)
%timeit python_sphj(4, x)
```

the result:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 28.1 µs per loop
```

Here is the results for 100000 elements:

```
x = np.linspace(1, 2, 100000)
r1 = cython_sphj2(4, x)
r2 = python_sphj(4, x)
assert np.allclose(r1, r2)
%timeit cython_sphj2(4, x)
%timeit python_sphj(4, x)
```

the result:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 44.7 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 231 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still interested, I found one solution nearly 17x faster than the one by Ted Pudlik. I used the fact that a spherical Bessel function of order n is essentially 1/sqrt(x) times a standard Bessel function of order n+1/2, which is already vectorized:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

sphj_bessel = lambda n, z: special.jv(n+1/2,z)*np.sqrt(np.pi/2)/(np.sqrt(z))
```

I got the following timings:

```
%timeit sphj_vectorize(2, x) # x = np.linspace(1, 2, 10**5)
1 loops, best of 3: 759 ms per loop

%timeit sphj_bessel(2,x) # x = np.linspace(1, 2, 10**5)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.6 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5623) incorporating vectorized spherical Bessel function routines into SciPy as `scipy.special.spherical_x`, with `x = jn, yn, in, kn`.  With a little luck, they should make it into version 0.18.0.

The performance improvement over `np.vectorize` (i.e., a for-loop) depends on the function, but can be orders of magnitude.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

@np.vectorize
def sphj_vectorize(n, z):
    return special.sph_jn(n, z)[0][-1]

x = np.linspace(1, 2, 10**5)

%timeit sphj_vectorize(4, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.47 s per loop

%timeit special.spherical_jn(4, x)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.07 ms per loop
```